# How to get real quotient in python 2

Tags: python-2.7

Since the division operator "/" only returns floor quotient.
When numerator or denominator is a minus number, operator "/" will not return the real quotient. Like -1/3 returns -1 rather than 0.
How can i get the real quotient?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the `/` operator is decided by the types of the of the operands. So if you want to have the real quotient, put in the numbers as `floats` like

```
float(1) / float(3)
```

or just

```
1.0 / 3.0
```

this also gives correct behavior with negative numbers.
If you want to get the correct int quotient, you can `math.ceil()` the negative number (or `math.floor()` for positives respectively)

EDIT:
Instead of using `math`, you can also just int() the result, which also gives correct results for negative numbers

Comment: It seems i have to do int(float(a)/float(b)) in general.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's probably the easiest way to get the behavior you want, also with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
a = 1
b = 3
print -(a / b)
```